# Is there any advantage to using AND and OR over && and || in PHP?

Tags: php, naming-conventions

In the [Kohana code conventions](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.conventions) it states that using `&&` and `||` is "incorrect":

[image]

Is there any advantage to using `AND` and `OR` other than clarity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The truth tables for the operators are the same, the only difference is precedence:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: +1 I didn't know that they had a precedence difference. You caused me to delete my answer. PHP is so sneaky. Even my Zend PHP Certification didn't prepare me for this surprise!

Comment: @Asaph - One can't really expect PHP to be consistent. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that whatever convention you choose to adopt you are consistent throughout. Otherwise precedence issues will haunt your code.

Comment: Or you can use brackets, which you should be doing anyway, for the sake of readability if nothing else.